# Astersik load balancing through fastagis

Tags: load-balancing, asterisk, fastagi

Thank you chochos for the reply. I am using softphones in my case so I do not know if your solution would be applicable in my case. Also how do you define groups and how do you associate channels to these groups in Asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

callgroups and pickupgroups are for zaptel/DAHDI, not for SIP, so no, my solution does not apply to your case.

Maybe you could name your SIP users so that the first (or last) 1 or 2 characters can be used in a similar way as I described earlier. I don't know why you opened a new question, we should be discussing this in answers to the original question.